# is it possible record computer sound and microphone at the same time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio-recording, python-sounddevice

I need to record a web call with python.

I managed to record the microphone voice with **sounddevice** module, but that's not what I want, I need to **record both microphone and computer sound** which is the other voice.

that's what I did to record the microphone:

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 5  # Duration of recording


myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file
```

I also tried to record the computer sound by changing the input device to the stereo mixer by adding this line before recording line:

```
sd.default.device = "stereo input", "speaker output"
```

but the output quality was really bad and that was just computer sound without microphone sound.

if there's any solution I really appreciate it

Comment: I need the same. Any solution?